# Move arrays with matching key value to new grouped array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have the below outputted PHP array by using var_dump($fields);

```
array() {
    [ 0 ] => array() {
        [ "state" ] => string( 3 ) "nsw"
        [ "address" ] => string( 13 ) "8 Test Street"
        [ "phone" ] => string( 12 ) "0000 000 000"
        [ "email" ] => string( 15 ) "info@123.com.au"
    }
    [ 1 ] => array() {
        [ "state" ] => string( 2 ) "wa"
        [ "address" ] => string( 13 ) "5 Test Street"
        [ "phone" ] => string( 12 ) "0000 000 000"
        [ "email" ] => string( 15 ) "info@123.com.au"
    }
    [ 2 ] => array() {
        [ "state" ] => string( 3 ) "qld"
        [ "address" ] => string( 13 ) "3 Test Street"
        [ "phone" ] => string( 12 ) "0000 000 000"
        [ "email" ] => string( 15 ) "info@123.com.au"
    }
    [ 3 ] => array() {
        [ "state" ] => string( 3 ) "nsw"
        [ "address" ] => string( 13 ) "1 Test Street"
        [ "phone" ] => string( 12 ) "0000 000 000"
        [ "email" ] => string( 15 ) "info@123.com.au"
    }
}
```

I would like to create a new array from all "state" keys present in $fields and shift corresponding values over so its like the below.

```
array() {
    [ "nsw" ] => array() {
        [0] => array() {
            [ "address" ] => string( 13 ) "8 Test Street"
            [ "phone" ] => string( 12 ) "0000 000 000"
            [ "email" ] => string( 15 ) "info@123.com.au"
        }
        [1] => array() {
            [ "address" ] => string( 13 ) "1 Test Street"
            [ "phone" ] => string( 12 ) "0000 000 000"
            [ "email" ] => string( 15 ) "info@123.com.au"
        }
    }
    [ "wa" ] => array() {
        [0] => array() {
            [ "address" ] => string( 13 ) "5 Test Street"
            [ "phone" ] => string( 12 ) "0000 000 000"
            [ "email" ] => string( 15 ) "info@123.com.au"
        }
    }
    [ "qld" ] => array() {
        [0] => array() {
            [ "address" ] => string( 13 ) "3 Test Street"
            [ "phone" ] => string( 12 ) "0000 000 000"
            [ "email" ] => string( 15 ) "info@123.com.au"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help, been searching for an answer on this with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a little bit logic.

```
<?php

$fields = [
    [
        "state" => "nsw",
        "address" => "8 Test Street",
        "phone" => "0000 000 000",
        "email" => "info@123.com.au",
    ],
    [
        "state" => "wa",
        "address" => "5 Test Street",
        "phone" => "0000 000 000",
        "email" => "info@123.com.au",
    ],
    [
        "state" => "qld",
        "address" => "3 Test Street",
        "phone" => "0000 000 000",
        "email" => "info@123.com.au",
    ],
    [
        "state" => "nsw",
        "address" => "1 Test Street",
        "phone" => "0000 000 000",
        "email" => "info@123.com.au",
    ]
];

$new = [];
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $state = $field['state'];
    unset($field['state']);
    $new[$state][] = $field;
}

print_r($new);

Array
(
    [nsw] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [address] => 8 Test Street
                    [phone] => 0000 000 000
                    [email] => info@123.com.au
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [address] => 1 Test Street
                    [phone] => 0000 000 000
                    [email] => info@123.com.au
                )

        )

    [wa] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [address] => 5 Test Street
                    [phone] => 0000 000 000
                    [email] => info@123.com.au
                )

        )

    [qld] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [address] => 3 Test Street
                    [phone] => 0000 000 000
                    [email] => info@123.com.au
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandr! Much appreciated.